# CSS dropdown menu with vertical subpage row

Tags: css, menu

Hello I need some help with a CSS drop down menu.

Normally you have the top level displayed horizontally and then the sub pages (ul li ul li) displayed vertically under each other. However the (ul li ul) is locked underneath its parent, I need the subpage level to span the width of the parent menu like in http://www.peverel.co.uk/ but just using CSS.

here is some basic code....

```
nav#navigation, nav#navigation ul{ padding:0; margin:0}
/*set up a tags*/ 
nav#navigation a{display:block;}
/*position level 1 links horizontally*/ 
nav#navigation li{display:block; float:left;}
/*undo previous style for level 2 links*/
nav#navigation li ul li{float:none;}
/*position level 2 links vertically and hide*/ 
nav#navigation li ul{display:none; position:absolute; z-index:1}
/*unhide level 2 links on li:hover from level 1*/ 
nav#navigation li:hover ul{
display:inline-block;
clear:both;
float:left;
position:absolute; 
z-index:1
}

nav#navigation ul li ul li{
display:inline-block;
clear:both;
float:left;
position:absolute; 
z-index:1;

}

/*DROPDOWN STYLING:*/
nav#navigation{height:25px}
nav#navigation a{color:#09F; padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;}
nav#navigation a:hover{color:#0CF;}
nav#navigation li{background-color:#FFF; border:solid 1px #CCC;  margin-left:-1px}
nav#navigation li:hover{background-color:#F0F0F0}




 <nav id="navigation" class="clearfix" role="navigation">
<ul>
<li class="page_item">
<a href=#">
    <ul class='children'>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="#">Cookie Policy</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="#">example sub page</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item"><a href="#">Blocks of Flats Insurance</a>
    <ul class='children'>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="#">Becoming An Appointed Representative</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="#">CHU Policy Launched</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
    <li class="page_item"><a href="#">Get a Quote</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

also this will be going onto a WordPress site

Comment: Right click on the navigation in http://www.peverel.co.uk/ and hit inspect element or view page source and you can see exactly how they did it. Works best in Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

To get 100% width spread evenly, use tables and table-cells. For example, the navigation should be a `table`, with the first-level links as `table-cell`.

Which is applied similarly to the lower levels.

http://jsfiddle.net/4T5yW/